# Flutter BLoC - How to pass parameter to event?

Tags: events, flutter, dart, parameters, bloc

Trying to learn BLoCs I came up with this problem. I have some code in which I generate some buttons with BLoC pattern. However, I have no clue how to update specific buttons properties with `dispatch(event)` method. How to pass parameters to the event `ChangeSomeValues`??

The part where the BLoC is used

```
BlocBuilder(
  bloc: myBloc,
  builder: (context, state) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: state.buttonList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return MyButton(
          label: buttonList[index].label,
          value: buttonList[index].value,
          onPressed: myBloc.dispatch(ChangeSomeValues()),
        );
      }
    );
  }
),
```

MyBloc.dart

```
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {

  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
    if (event is ChangeSomeValues) {
      ... modify specific parameters in list here ...
      yield MyState1(modifiedList);
    }
  }
}
```

I know how to use the events to change values but I couldn't find how to edit specific parameters in list with this kind of a generic implementation.

Comment: i dont get it: you dont know how to pass a parameter to `ChangeSomeValues()` constructor?

Comment: It's an event. If I pass some parameters to the constructor how will that ```if``` clause work?

Comment: `if (event is ChangeSomeValues) {` ? of course

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Code for your event :

```
class ChangeSomeValues extends MyEvent {
  final int data;

  ChangeSomeValues(this.data);
}
```

dispatch it as : `myBloc.dispatch(ChangeSomeValues(15))`

The bloc

```
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {

  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
    if (event is ChangeSomeValues) {
      print("here's the data : ${event.data}");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Do you know why those builder generated buttons won't update when clicked? After hot reload I see the updated states but not before

Comment: Figured it out: I had to change state into something else and then back to update the BlocBuilder